# WPF Data Binding an ObservableCollection (or LinkedList) to a WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, properties

Ok. First of all, I've looked at a bunch of other questions and a ton of other places on the internet on how to do this, and none of them are helping, so please don't mark this as a duplicate, and also, heads up cause I probably made a really stupid mistake.

I'm trying to bind an `ObservableCollection` to a `WrapPanel` using an `ItemsControl` and a `DataTemplate`. The following is my XAML Code:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="wPanel">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--<Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" Background="Transparent">-->
                <StackPanel MinWidth="250">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding address}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            <!--</Border>-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Note:** I did have (for the ItemsSource property of ItemsControl) `{Binding properties}`

This is my declaration of `properties`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Property> properties = new ObservableCollection<Property>();
```

And the Property Class is the following plus many more properties:

```
private string address { get; set; }
private string city { get; set; }
private string postcode { get; set; }
private double price { get; set; }
private LinkedList<Tennant> tennants { get; set; }
...
```

I thought I had solved the problem with this,

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = properties;
wPanel.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

But, then the line in the xaml: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding address}" />` didn't work.

Then I came to the conclusion that it had to do with the properties object, and how it wouldn't bind unless I did it through code.

What am I doing wrong, for it not bind through XAML, etc.? What do I need to change about the properties object, or what do I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind ItemsControl's ItemsSource to properties just like @AjS answer. But before that, you need to change properties declaration to be property instead of field.

```
public ObservableCollection<Property> properties { get; set; }
```

And also address property of your `Property` class need to be public.

```
public string address { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the 'properties' a property on the window?
If you are binding in xaml, make sure you use declare 'properties' as 'Property', set datacontext of window to itself and then set binding path:-

```
         <ItemsControl x:Name="wPanel" ItemsSource="{Binding properties}">
           this.DataContext=this;  //set datacontext on parent window or control
```

If you are doing it in code, setting the ItemsSource directly on wPanel should work:-

```
           wPanel.ItemsSource=properties;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy trick for check `Binding`. Every WPF developer must know this. For example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
```

Run and see it.

If `TextBlock` has any object in DataContext, `object class name` displayed in TextBlock. 
If `DataContext` has empty. TextBlock is `Empty`